# In Logstash, how to get public IP address of a client as field

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am sending logs from my node to logstash using file beat.
There are multiple such a kind of nodes who are sending logs to logstash using file beat.

Basically I want to know the public IP address of my node so that I can plot a visualization in KIBANA with geoip based location.

And as my node is behind NAT, I can't print IP address as part of my log entry (eg., syslog entry); because locally I know only private IP of the node.

Is there any way that logstash can automatically know my node's IP address and insert it as a elastic search field?

Theoretically it should be possible as when logstash gets the information from beats, he should be knowing the IP address from where he is getting that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't understand your question. You should rephrase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with the current Logstash Beats input to configure it to enrich incoming events with the remote IP from which the event was received.

This feature was [proposed](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-lumberjack/pull/3) in the past for the older Logstash Lumberjack input, but there isn't an [open](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/issues) feature request for this in the Beats input. I suggest you request it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So is there any work around or trick you can think of to make this possible without having features in built into Beats which may take time?

Comment: If the Beat is behind NAT and doesn't know its public IP, then there is no workaround. The IP would have to be added by Logstash which will require a code change (probably a simple one, but still a change).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-beats/issues/180
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html#plugins-inputs-beats-ecs_metadata

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
        add_field => { "remote_ip" => "%{[@metadata][input][beats][host].[ip]}" }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).